# Webpack Babel config

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

so I'm completing a course on how to create WP blocks w/ React and Redux and there is chapter in this course about how to setup your Webpack for all of it.
My problem is kinda simple, but I've no idea where I went wrong.

When I make a mistake in my JSX console has to log a Warning w/ a line number where that mistake was made, also it has to relate to file from the ./src folder and not from the ./dist one.

These are my files: index.js, index.html, MyComponent.js, package.json and webpack.config.js:

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### package.json

```js
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode=development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@wordpress/browserslist-config": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.16.1",
    "webpack": "^5.17.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "extends @wordpress/browserslist-config"
  ]
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    var config = {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                '@babel/preset-env',
                                [
                                    '@babel/preset-react',
                                    {
                                        "pragma": "React.createElement",
                                        "pragmaFrag": "React.Fragment",
                                        "development": argv.mode === 'development'
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    return config;
}
```

#### index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent';

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent title="Hey" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### MyComponent.js

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log('wwdwdw');
        return <div>
            {[1,2,3].map(item => <div>{item}</div>)}
        </div>
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

And finally my console output:

```
wwdwdw MyComponent.js:5
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `MyComponent`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at div
    at MyComponent (http://webpack/dist/bundle.js:45:5)
```

Ony thing is right, because of source-maps console says that 'wwdwdw' was logged from a line 5 (and its correct), but for the warning it refers to the compiled file from ./dist and I want it to say something like 'MyComponent.js:7'

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not a problem with webpack or babel, it's from your `MyComponent.js` file, you use a map and didn't give item a unique key, which react use to detect if the item should be rerender next time.

This post from react official website may help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys